# Incremental training of xgboost with fewer classes present

Tags: python, xgboost

I encountered a problem when training an incremental xgboost model. If my incremental dataset contains samples in every category, incremental training works well. Anyhow, if the dataset does not contain samples from every category, the training fails.

MRE:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as ttsplit
import xgboost as xgb

X = load_iris()['data']
y = load_iris()['target']

# split data into training and testing sets
# then split training set in half for base model and incremental model
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ttsplit(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
X_train_1, X_train_2, y_train_1, y_train_2 = ttsplit(
    X_train, y_train, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False)
clf.fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)

# Artificially remove one group from the labels to showcase behavior
y_train_2[y_train_2 == 0] = 1
clf2 = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False)
clf2.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2, xgb_model=clf)
```

Results in:

```
ValueError: The label must consist of integer labels of form 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1].
```

This is expected behavior with a fresh training from scratch, but it's not convenient to expect the incremental dataset to have samples in every category. What can I do to overcome this limitation?

Comment: I am running into the same. did you find any solution?

Comment: It seems that xgboost is not designed to do incremental training per se, but the incremental feature can be used for multibatch training (helps with resource restrictions). Doing incremental training won't update the trees themselves but only their weights. Thus we decided to do only fullbatch trainings as the training time was reasonable